# How to Subtract/Add 3 or more Date Time variables

Tags: vb.net

I tried below codes for calculate overtime. but only I can deal with 2 datetime variable. if I add third one it gave me an error.

[image]

```
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCalculate.Click

Dim intime As DateTime

intime = dtIN.Value

Dim outtime As DateTime

outtime = dtOut.Value

Dim norhrs As DateTime = dtnhrs.Value

Dim overtime As TimeSpan

overtime = outtime - intime-norhrs

If txtgrade.Text < 6 Then

txtOT.Text = overtime.ToString

Else : txtOT.Text = "Not Eligible For Overtime"

End If
```

Comment: Got error `overtime = outtime - intime-norhrs` here ?

Comment: Yes. error appeared in that section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). This will tell you what the problem is: you cannot subtract a datetime from a timespan. Subtracting one datetime from another gives a timespan.

Note that a DateTimePicker has both a date and a time in its value, regardless of what you see displayed. For the normal hours, you only want the time component.

The value you get from the textbox for the grade is a String - you need to convert it to a number before you can compare it to another number. It is possible that someone will forget to enter the grade, but you can check for that easily enough.

There is no point doing the O/T calculation if it is not going to be used, so that portion of code can be moved.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim grade As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(txtgrade.Text, grade) Then
        If grade < 6 Then
            Dim intime As DateTime = dtIN.Value
            Dim outtime As DateTime = dtOut.Value
            Dim norhrs As TimeSpan = dtnhrs.Value.TimeOfDay
            Dim overtime As TimeSpan = outtime - intime - norhrs
            'TODO: Format the overtime neatly.
            txtOT.Text = overtime.ToString

        Else
            txtOT.Text = "Not eligible For overtime"

        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a number for the grade.")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have that first sentence in a macro or something?  ;)

Comment: @Plutonix I am expecting it to be the number one search term on Google if I answer many more VB questions. Maybe I should look the link up on Bing so that MS get the hint :)